# responding to different device name for different Bluetooth discovery request

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I want to write an application which respond different device name for different Bluetooth device discovery request. For example, I have two mobile phones A and B. I want to show my laptop Bluetooth device name as "device1" for "A" and as "device2" for "B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth software stacks generally (always?) cache the remote device names (and it can be very hard to get them to forget the old name and re-read it)...

So set your device to have device name "device1" get "A" to discover it, then change its name to "device2" and get "B" to discover it.  "A" will always know it as "device1" and "B" will always know it as "device2". :-)